Will ESTA be denied after tourist visa denial 5 years ago?
I was refused a tourist visa for the US 5 years ago because I was between jobs and I was applying from my home country where I didn’t actually live. I recently got a passport from my new home country which is in the visa waiver program and I am wondering will I be refused an ESTA application because of that tourist visa denial 5 years ago?
Thank you so much!

The only way to be sure is to apply and find out.

Don’t forget: answer all questions honestly and truthfully. And the fact that you got a new citizenship or passport does not change the answers to any “did you ever…” questions.

Of course I would answer honestly all questions regardless of the new passport; my question is more about whether a tourist visa denial 5 years ago automatically leads to an ESTA denial, or there are people in this forum who have a positive experience
